# Plague attacks all except postal workers

Tags: story-identification

Can anyone identify a short story about a plague which is sweeping the US attacking everyone without distinction - except Post Office workers?

It eventually turn out to be passed on  by licking infected postage stamps.

> Post Office workers are exempt because they do not lick stamps, but use a sponge.

Comment: Duplicate of [Disease transmitted by postage stamps](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/216926/98028). I won't cast a close vote, both because there's no answer here yet and my story-id close votes are bidding, but if you confirm it's the same, you can self-close your own question; the earlier one is a good target, as it remembered more details.

Comment: Duplicate of Disease transmitted by postage stamps.

Comment: I closed as you confirmed it was the same story.